UV Sampling Geometry Nodes
I've been working on a digital fashion project. I've been working with Marvelous Designer and Blender. My plan is to build a low poly mesh and get my cloth simulation in Marveouls Designer and import it as an alembic to Blender and give it more detailed texturing and a more high poly mesh in Blender with a geo node tree that functions as a UV sampler. The UV sampler is sampling the UVs from my low poly mesh so that I can basically edit the geometry in any way I want and give it as much detail as I would want. But it is not working as I wish it would be and some parts of the mesh are always pulled to the origin. but I don't understand where the bug is coming from. I've attached a picture and a WeTransfer Link to the file.
WeTransfer File Link




On the last Sample UV Surface > Set Position some points have Is Valid to false. From the manual : "Is Valid: Whether the node could find a single face to sample at the UV coordinate." I can't help you more than that. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/mesh/sample/sample_uv_surface.html
